# AC voltage measurement with an op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, ac, isolation

I want to know if there is a problem with the circuit of the picture, I need to measure 120 VAC. In this example, there are not isolation and I don't want to fry my PC. Any tip?

- The output of the op-amp is conected to an STM32 analog input.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting your supplies from? Where's the local ground connected to? And, 470k is a bit high for a 358 *(considering the fact that the input bias currents can be as high as 45nA)* if you expect high accuracy.

Comment: You mean 120 VAC 60 Hz mains supply power? Some people might use a small transformer in that application.